# Can't connect to WebService using WebRequest / WebResponse

Tags: asp.net, .net, vba

Unsuccessfully trying to connect to web service.

User enters URL for WebService,in my case it is `http://localhost:61302/WebService/XYZService.asmx`, enters username/login (for testing purposes I use `alexTest`/`deJh8detRKw=`), and clicks `Test Connection` button, which should connect to `public int TestConnect(string userName, string password)` web service method.

Here is handler for button click

```
 Private Sub Test_Connection_2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TestButton_2.Click
        If URL_Field.Text.Trim <> "" Then
            ' URL string is not empty

            Try 'Attempt to connect to Web Services
                'TODO: Add the Uri(URL_Field.Text.Trim + function name)
                Dim base_uri As New Uri(URL_Field.Text.Trim) 'URL Server
                Dim combined_uri As New Uri(URL_Field.Text.Trim + "/TestConnect")
                'TODO: Parse the service_uri to make sure it is syntat. correct URL or handle the exception during constr

                Dim web_request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(combined_uri)
                web_request.Method = "POST"
                web_request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                Dim string_data As String = String.Format("userName={0}&password={1}", userNameBox.Text.Trim(), Uri.EscapeDataString(passBox.Text.Trim()))
                Dim byte_data() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string_data)
                web_request.ContentLength = byte_data.Length

                'Get Response 
                Dim web_resp As HttpWebResponse = web_request.GetResponse()
                Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(web_resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
                Dim response_string As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

It runs to the line `Dim web_resp As HttpWebResponse = web_request.GetResponse()` and stops. I get no exceptions, no errors, nothing. 
Web Service works, since I was able to test it through the browser. However, when I ran my code does not stop at breakpoint placed on the web method, i.e web method is never invoked.

Comment: Does it work from the browser? Why are you using WebRequest? See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, it works fine in the browser. However, trying to reach it thought the code, that is the problem.

Comment: Why are you using that technique instead of "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, because I always used it and because my entire code base is written this way (I am reworking old VBA code). I had no problems in the past.

Comment: @JohnSaunders This appears to be VBA code, probably run from Excel. I don't think you can just add a service reference like you can with Visual Studio.

Comment: @mason s this is an old Windows Form application written in VBA in Visual Studio (I am staring at VS right now)